# Uploading an Audio file from Phonegap to Clypit

Tags: ios, cordova, file-upload, file-transfer

I am using the FileTransfer Object with Phonegap.  I am attempting to upload the file  to Clypit according to their API http://clyp.it/api  which says you can upload a file from a form upload to this url http://upload.clyp.it/upload.  I have tested this in a normal web browser and it works.

However, it is slightly different from an IOS device as when you use a file select input form they only allow access to the picture gallery.  I need to upload a recorded piece of audio.

So I have used the following code:

```
 function shareRecording(rec){
    window.shareFile = rec;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, shareFileSystemSuccess, fail);
}

function shareFileSystemSuccess(fs){
    fs.root.getFile(window.shareFile, {create: false}, gotShareFileSuccess, fail);
}

function gotShareFileSuccess(fileEntry){
    uploadToClypit(fileEntry);
}

function uploadToClypit(file){
    console.log(file);

      var options = new FileUploadOptions();
      options.name= file.fullPath.substr(file.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/')+ 1);
      console.log(options);

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    console.log(file.nativeURL);
    ft.upload(file.nativeURL, encodeURI("http://upload.clyp.it/upload"), win, failUpload);

}

var win = function(r){
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

var failUpload = function(error){
    console.log(error);
}
```

My understanding is that the FileTransfer() object creates a HTTP multi-part POST request so this should mimic what is happening in a normal web browser with a form.  But I receive a fileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR I have tried debugging this with the Safari WEb Inspector and unfortunately I cannot see the request being sent of the network.  I had thought it might be a problem with Clypit but the request is never sent it is failing before it is ever sent.  Any ideas what I have wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - First of all I wasn't passing the options as a parameter into the ft.upload  and secondly I wasn't setting the write parameters that Clypit requires.

So it now looks like this:

```
function uploadToClypit(file){
console.log(file);

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.name = file.fullPath.substr(file.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/')+ 1);
options.audioFile = file.nativeURL;
options.fileName = file.nativeURL;
options.mimeType = "audio/wav";
options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
}
options.chunkedMode = false;
console.log(options);

var ft = new FileTransfer();
console.log(file.nativeURL);
ft.upload(file.nativeURL, encodeURI("http://upload.clyp.it/upload"), win, failUpload, options);
```

}